# passing function parameters in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

i am interested in passing function parameters using rpy2.  my function in R is normally called as follows:

```
rtn_val <- fn(param1="str_param1",
              a.b.param2=NULL,
              param3=7,
              param4=FALSE)
```

**fn** is contained in a library called **MyLib**.  so far, my python code looks like this:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
my_lib = importr("MyLib")
```

i am not sure how to pass the relevant parameters to **my_lib.fn**.  any guidance is much appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: You are calling `param2` twice. Please advise.

Comment: @Parfait, sorry.  the post has been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and call it like any named Python function but be sure to replace periods in parameters with underscores, `NULL` value as `None`, and proper case of `False`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
my_lib = importr("MyLib")

rtn_val = my_lib.fn(param1 = "str_param1",
                    a_b_param2 = None,
                    param3 = 7,
                    param4 = False)
```